# run program from flash drive with vbs

Tags: vbscript

HI i was trying to make script to execute program from flash drive but it doesn't work and here is my script

```
Set wshShell = wScript.CreateObject("wScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For Each objDrive In objFSO.Drives
If objDrive.DriveType = 1 Then
wshShell.run objDrive.DriveLetter & "\ \Autoit\Scripts\Google Chrome\Delete.vbs"
End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Guys just figured it out by my self so the problem is the objDrive.DriveLetter and instead of using that one i use this script and works fine haha thanks

```
Set wshShell = wScript.CreateObject("wScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For Each objDrive In objFSO.Drives
If objDrive.DriveType = 1 Then
wshShell.run ("""\ \Autoit\Scripts\Google Chrome\Delete.vbs""")
End If
Next
```